# What language does chaincode use in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

What language does chaincode use in Hyperledger Fabric? I couldn't find the answer anywhere. I am new to Hyperledger Fabric and would like to start developing immediately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go and node.js are supported.

Source: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/chaincode.html